# Simple Square Wave Amplification Technique?

Tags: square, step-up

I have a square wave that is 5v peak-to-peak. I need a circuit that can amplify this square wave up to any given supply voltage between 9 and 50v. I don't need much current, nothing more than 100ma certainly, 20-50ma would work. My preference is to use components as cheap as I can get. How can I amplify this square wave for minimal component cost? Is there a way to achieve a square wave with a high peak-to peak voltage without in input pwm?

**Edit:**

The 0-Vsupply square wave will be fed into the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkW8Rs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Vout will always float 10v above the supply, minus a few diode drops. The part I am stuck on is how to get a square wave at the supply voltage.

Comment: Use a transformer.

Comment: @Andyaka I will already have a supply voltage available between 9 and 50v. I see all kinds of level shifters out there but they only work for lower voltages.

Comment: "... for minimal component cost?" - that depends. How much signal current is available at 5V, what is the frequency range, and what are low/high voltages (eg. 0-5V)? How fast does the output have to transition, and how close does it have to get to the supply rails at 50mA? What load is it driving?

Comment: @BruceAbbott none of these parameters are critical. Let me add a schematic.

Comment: Is there a terminology confusion?  Circuit designers see "step up" and they think you want to increase the voltage in some mostly-lossless way, like a transformer or a boost power supply.  But you mention having higher-voltage supplies -- do you mean you want to *amplify* your square wave, i.e., do you just want it reproduced only at higher voltage?

Comment: @TimWescott Yes I want to amplify the signal. I will edit the post to reflect.

Comment: I'm going to answer your question, but -- is this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)?  It looks like maybe your real question should be "how do I get a low-current supply that floats 10V above my 50V supply rail?"

Comment: There certainly will be more unspecified current issues driving 50V pulses @ 1kHz charging up 1uF with a few ohms ESR and some load resistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind burning up power, but want simple.  You need to size your resistors to match whatever you choose for C1 (so if C1 = 1uF, choose R = 100 ohms, which means that Q1 needs to be a power transistor, not a cheezy little 3904).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW8r1F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you want to be more efficient, but can stand more drop (the output will pull down to about 0.9V, and up to 50V - 0.7V).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0nKCp.png)</sup>

Comment: is 2N3904 ok at 50v?

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple circuit that works for me. Just tested on my oscilloscope. I had originally overlooked this one because power dissipation goes up with supply voltage, but in my application a very small on-time duty cycle will suffice. This will decrease the average power dissipation through the collector resistor to within an acceptable range.

[image]

Schematic by Herbert Weidner

Comment: You'll get better turn-off of the transistor if you put a 1k-ohm resistor from base to ground.  I'm pretty sure that a 5k-ohm resistor won't give you enough oomph with your chosen 1uF cap, unless your entire circuit is fairly lightly loaded.

Comment: What transistor are you using, and what are the on and off times?